# Future waiting for FixedThreadPool is returning before all Threads finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to wait all my threads finish before execute another task using Future, but something is wrong because my future is just wainting for the last thread of my for loop.

My executor method:

```
public static Future<?> downloadImages(Executor e, MainViewController controller, String filePath, String dns, int port, int numImg,
            String offlineUuid, Map<String, String> cookies, String type, String outputFolder) throws SystemException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        String urlImages;
        String filePath2;
        Future future = null;

        if (numImg == 1) {

         //Some Code

        } else {

            type = "multimages";
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numImg);


            for (int i = 0; i < numImg; i++) {
                filePath2 = "";
                filePath2 = filePath + File.separator + "TargetApp" + File.separator + "TempImage" + i + "Download.zip";
                urlImages = "http://" + dns + ":" + port + Constants.TARGET_SERVICE_DOWNLOADIMAGES_PATH + offlineUuid + "/?pos=" + (i);

                future = es.submit(new DownloaderAndUnzipTask(controller, urlImages, filePath2, outputFolder, cookies, type));
            }

            return future;
        }
        return null;

    }
```

My waiting method:

```
Future future = fullDownloadSelected(tableViewFull.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
                        if (future != null) {
                            try {
                                future.get();
                                if (future.isDone());
                                System.out.println("Processamento de Imagens Acabou");
                            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
```

My msg is shown when the last Thread created in first method is finished,  but it should have finished when all threads in pool is finished. I think something is wrong where I submit my executor inside the for loop, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture every Future returned and then wait for each one to complete (using get on each)

You can, alternatively, do something like:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numImg);
List<Callable> tasks = ...
for (int i = 0; i < numImg; i++) {
  tasks.add(your tasks);
}
List<Future<Object>> futures = es.invokeAll(tasks);
```

which will only return once all the tasks within are complete.

Answer (score 1):

You are just waiting for the last `Future` to finish.

```
   future = es.submit(...);
   ...
return future;
...
// in waiting method, wait for the last job to finish
future.get();
```

This only waits for the last of the jobs submitted to the executor-service to finish -- other jobs can still be running.  You should instead return the `ExecutorService` from the `downloadImages()`.  Then in your waiting method you do:

```
// you must always shut the service down, no more jobs can be submitted
es.shutdown();
// waits for the service to complete forever
es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

It may make more sense for you to create your `ExecutorService` in the calling method and pass it into the `downloadImages()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning the future in each iteration.
You can use [invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) which returns when all submitted tasks are done.